# How to select elements from an array according its index

Tags: arrays, ruby, select

I'm a newby and maybe this is very simple. But how could I select specific elements from an array according its index. I have an array with 108 elements. I need to select some of them according a few index positions that I already know. I guess I could do by concantenating '&', but there should be a better way. This is the code I've been trying

```
def first_position(entry)
  array_entry = entry.split('')
  spots_first_position = array_entry.select { |spot| spot.index = [0,1,2,28,29,30,55,56,57]}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use :

```
your_array.values_at(*indices_array)
```

Look at the documentation of [`Array#values_at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-values_at)